# Нет перегруженного метода, который соответствует делегату

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CSCore;
using CSCore.SoundIn;
using CSCore.Codecs.WAV;

namespace SoundTransfer
{
  public class BackEnd
  {

    public void Record()
    {
        using (WasapiCapture capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture())
        {
            capture.Initialize();

            using (WaveWriter w = new WaveWriter("dump.wav", capture.WaveFormat))
            {
                capture.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
                {
                    w.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
                };
                void Timer()
                {
                    int num = 0;
                    TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(Switch);//Ошибка
                    Timer timer = new Timer(tm, num, 0, 10);
                }

                void Switch(String command)
                {
                    if (command == "start")
                    {
                        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                        window.BlockChanger(command);
                    }
                    else if (command == "stop")
                    {
                        //capture.Stop();
                        capture.Dispose();
                        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                        window.BlockChanger(command);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
}
```

В создании калбека вылазит ошибка из заголовка. Что делать?

Comment: `Что делать?` - для начала указать что за ошибка и почему вы думаете, что каллбек для таймера вдруг будет принимать строку как параметр.

Comment: Нет перегруженного метода для "Switch", который соответствует делегату "TimerCallback"

Comment: Ну то есть вам прямо текстом написано что не так - сигнатура вашего `Switch` не совпадает с тем, что ожидает каллбек таймера. Согласно [докам](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timercallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  метод должен быть void и принимать параметр как `object`, а у вас вместо объекта - строка.

Comment: да и логика вашего `Switch` непонятна - почему вы решили, что таймер, которому дела нет до каких то команд, вдруг начнет посылать команды в метод `Switch`? Он этого делать сам не будет, вам надо писать какую то доп логику для того, чтобы в ваш метод посылались команды, что вы хотите

Comment: хочу вызывать метод Switch через равные промежутки времени

Comment: Ну а с какой командой вы хотите его вызывать? Что должно быть в параметре метода в этот момент?

Comment: Да без разницы, главное его вызывать

Comment: ну тогда вам нужен метод, что принимает `object` как параметр (а уже в этом методе вызывайте что хотите) + вам надо будет сделать таймер полем класса, иначе GC его уничтожит. И это вроде все, что вам необходимо для решения вашей задачи.